# Drupal Views Ajax refresh rows

Tags: ajax, drupal, view, refresh, rows

I have some view (Views 2 - list of invitations, table style) which uses embedded forms to edit records directly in view rows.
I am using ahah to change values in records. What I need is to refresh all records dynamically (some calculations) after I change some checkboxes.
Is there any way to refresh view using Ajax?
To trigger reload table rows only form the code?
I suspect it must be some way (some command) as there is a Use Ajax option in views for sorting tables, etc...

Any hints would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In basic settings there is the 'use ajax' option which :

> If set, this view will use an AJAX mechanism for paging, table sorting and exposed filters. This means the entire page will not refresh. It is not recommended that you use this if this view is the main content of the page as it will prevent deep linking to specific pages, but it is very useful for side content.

you may find the module [Ajax Views Refresh](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_views_refresh) useful

Comment: This view is used only for administrators not to be indexes by search engines, etcc. so using Ajax is most convenient here.
I do not want to install separate module for such a simple functionality. I am sure some function is triggered when user updates a filter or changes sorting...

Comment: I took a look at the module and its pretty small, totaling less than 100 lines of code for the .js and .module files combined. Probably would be worth a try.